# Difference between toJSON() and JSON.Stringify()

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

> if you need to read or clone all of a model’s data attributes, use its
> toJSON() method. This method returns a copy of the attributes as an
> object (not a JSON string despite its name). (When JSON.stringify() is
> passed an object with a toJSON() method, it stringifies the return
> value of toJSON() instead of the original object. The examples in the
> previous section took advantage of this feature when they called
> JSON.stringify() to log model instances.)

http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#backbone-basics

Can anyone tell me the difference between both these ways of "representing an object" in JSON notation. I am just confused whether these to achieve the same or there is a difference.

Comment: @Pekka웃: i tried, but did not get any good results. https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Difference+between+toJSON%28%29+and+JSON.Stringify%28%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gws_rd=cr&ei=9G23UrOaIYH3rQfkroHwCw

Comment: I believe `toJSON()` returns a value that `JSON.stringify()` can then convert in to JSON text. I believe this is handy when using things like Date objects. This is from what I remember reading.

Comment: @MatthewPaxman: Sort of. `JSON.stringify` will call `toJSON` itself to figure out an object's JSON representation.

Comment: @Pekka웃 yeah and a google search should lead you to a StackOverflow question :)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior):

> **toJSON behavior**
>
> If an object being stringified has a property named `toJSON` whose value is a function, then the `toJSON` method customizes JSON stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the value returned by the `toJSON` method when called will be serialized.

This is why Backbone uses the [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) method for serialization and given a model instance called `m`, you can say things like:

```
var string = JSON.stringify(m);
```

and get just the attributes out of `m` rather than a bunch of noise that your server won't care about.

That said, the main difference is that `toJSON` produces a value (a number, boolean, object, ...) that gets converted to a JSON string whereas `JSON.stringify` always produces a string.

The [default Backbone `toJSON`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.0/backbone.js#L277) is simply this (for models):

```
return _.clone(this.attributes);
```

so `m.toJSON()` gives you a *shallow* copy of the model's attributes. If there are arrays or objects as attribute values then you will end unexpected reference sharing. Note that [`Backbone.Model#clone`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-clone) also [suffers from this problem](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.0/backbone.js#L542).

If you want to safely clone a model's data then you could send it through `JSON.stringify` and then `JSON.parse` to get a deep copy:

```
var data         = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(model_instance));
var cloned_model = new M(data);
```

where `model_instance` is your instance of the Backbone model `M`.

Answer (score 14):

- `JSON.stringify()` - Any valid JSON representation value can be stringified.

  The `JSON.stringify(..)` utility will automatically omit `undefined`, `function`, and `symbol` values when it comes across them. If such a value is found in an **`array`**, that value is replaced by `null` (so that the array position information isn't altered). If found as a property of an **`object`**, that property will simply be excluded.

  JSON stringification has the special behavior that if an `object` value has a `toJSON()` method defined, this method will be called first to get a value to use for serialization.
- `toJSON()` - to a valid JSON value suitable for stringification.

  One example, `JSON.stringify()` an `object` with circular reference in it, an error will be thrown. `toJSON()` can fix it as following.

  ```
  var o = { };
  var a = {
      b: 32,
      c: o
  };

  // circular reference
  o.d = a;

  // JSON.stringify( a ); // an error caused by circular reference

  // define toJSON method
  a.toJSON = function() {
       return { b: this.b };
  };

  JSON.stringify( a ); // "{"b":32}"
  ```

Comment: how do you fix an instance of a class that when input into stringify comes out as {}

Answer (score 3):

I'm also reading Addy Osmani's [Developing backbone.js application](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#collections), and I have the same question. I figured out by trying his example (the todo list) in the console.

```
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
         title:"",
         completed:false
}
});

var todo1 = new Todo(); 


console.log(todo1.toJSON())
//The console shows
//Object {title: "finish your assignment", completed: false}

console.log(JSON.stringify(todo1))
//The console shows
//{"title":"finish your assignment","completed":false}
```