# Unable to pass result of a query to view and render into JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform, handlebars.js

I am trying to query a Parse table and I am able to get the data out. I am then passing that data to a Parse View to be rendered into a handlebar template. The view in itself is working when I manually input JSON data into the collection variable.

My problem is that the data is not getting passed to the View from the query or not getting converted to JSON. I keep getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.collection.toJSON is not a function

```
// render template with context data 
var StoresView =  Parse.View.extend({
template: Handlebars.compile($('#storetable-tpl').html()),
render: function(){ 
    var collection = { storeList: this.collection.toJSON() };
    this.$el.html(this.template(collection));
}
});

// query the store table data
allStores.equalTo("shape","Round");
allStores.limit(10);
allStores.descending("updatedAt");
allStores.find({
success: function(results) {
    var storesView = new StoresView({ collection: results });
    storesView.render();
    $('#stores-table').html(storesView.el);
} 
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just noticed, the issues is not of passing the data from query to view. Coz when I change the 'code'var collection = { storeList: this.collection }; Then I get the data in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you are encoding, but not decoding? Also, I will check the type of `this.collection`, especially `this`. Since [Backbone.toJSON()](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.0/backbone.js#L277) applies to models.

> ex. to encode using [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for converting objects to json string to store in db and to decode when after retrieving from db using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

[Backbone uses .toJSON()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) and [this post explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20735169/4749156) further on serialization/deserialzation in backbone

Comment: Thats awesome thanks. I think it wasnt working coz I was trying to use that function without including backbone.js. Your link helped out and it works now using these parse and stringify together. var collection = { storeList: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.collection)) };

Comment: Great! Glad that helped. Yes. Remember to encode and decode :) in your case, both!

Comment: Upvote if it helped! Since it had value in regards to serialization Cheers

Comment: I wanted to but I do not have enough reputation points it seems.