# JSON.stringify() - how to know current depth in replacer

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have recursivity problem when trying to stringify an object.

I wonder if anyone have a tip to know what is the current depth when iterating trough key -> value in the replacer ?
I want to replace a reference by its ID, but only when I'm at a specific depth.

Here is a minimalist object to give an exemple :

```
var a = {
  id: 'idOfA',
  linkedItems: []
};

var b = {
  id: 'idOfB',
  linkedItems: []
};

var c = {
  id: 'idOfC',
  linkedItems: []
};

a.linkedItems.push({
  from: 0,
  to: 0,
  item: b
});
b.linkedItems.push({
  from: 0,
  to: 0,
  item: a
}, {
  from: 0,
  to: 0,
  item: c
});
c.linkedItems.push({
  from: 0,
  to: 0,
  item: a
}, {
  from: 0,
  to: 0,
  item: b
});

var obj = {
  things: {},
  otherThings: {},
  items: [a, b, c]
};
```

From obj, I need to replace each references in the "linkedItems" attribute, by their id.
I tough the easier way was to stringify it first ... :)

Comment: write relevant code.. write your attempt

Comment: show your input data

Comment: The "replacer" is really just a filtering mechanism, it doesn't keep count of the depth in the object being stringified.

Comment: Sorry, congratulations on being one of the few people in the world to take advantage of the replacer, which is a grossly under-utilized feature, but it won't help you here.

Comment: I see... :(. I added more informations ! :)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest The input data is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI There is no point in asking for an attempt. Either the replacer can access the current depth, or it can't. In this particular case, it can't.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant that :). I wrote it quickly to give an idea. Let me correct it :)

Comment: Here it is, I made a fully rewrited exemple, which can be compiled :p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way. But I'm not sure it's the optimal way to do it :s.

here is what I added :

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'map', {
    value: function (f, ctx) {
        ctx = ctx || this;
        var self = this;
        var result = {};
        Object.keys(self).forEach(function (k) {
            result[k] = f.call(ctx, self[k], k, self);
        });

        return result;
    }
});

var okayItems = obj.items.map(function (item, index) {
    item = Object.assign({}, item, {
        linkedItems: item.linkedItems.map(function (linkedItem) {
            linkedItem = linkedItem.map(function (value, key) {
                return (key === 'item') ? value.id : value;
            });

            return linkedItem;
        })
    });

    return item;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume what you call "references" (`a` ,`b` & `c`) are String .

```js
var a="SA", b="SB", c="SC" ;

var obj = {
  things: {},
  otherThings: {},
  items: {
    a: {
      _id: 'idOfA',
      linkedItems: [b, c]
    },
    b: {
      _id: 'idOfB',
      linkedItems: [a]
    },
    c: {
      _id: 'idOfC',
      linkedItems: [a, b]
    }
  }
}
function getID(attr){
   var mapping={'SA':'a','SB':'b','SC':'c'};
   return obj.items[mapping[attr]]._id;
   

};

Object.keys(obj.items).map((value, index) =>{
  obj.items[value].linkedItems = obj.items[value].linkedItems.map((e)=>getID(e));
});

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any possible way to adapt this to my needs :s.
You can check my first post for more details :)

Answer (score -1):

You can implement the `toJson` function into the object of yours, and handle this case within it, then when you call `JSON.stringify` it will be returned from that object.

[Difference between toJSON() and JSON.Stringify()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734894/difference-between-tojson-and-json-stringify)

Comment: I already tried this :). The problem is that it will always return the id even on items which aren't deep enough in my object.