# knex with related returns collection bases

Tags: node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

In a NodeJS/Knex/Bookshelf app I'm helping to rewrite, I'm doing a `withRelated` query on `User` model for messages and interests:

```
  return User.query({where: {id: user.id}})
      .fetch({withRelated: ['messages', 'interests']}).then(function(user) {
        return {
          id: user.id,
          prop1: user.related('messages'),
          prop2: user.related('interests'),
        };
      });
```

But it's returning back CollectionBases:

```
{ id: 1,
  messages: 
    CollectionBase {
     model: { ... }
    }
   }
  interests:
    CollectionBase {
     model: { ... }
    }
  }
```

But I need it to return the actual arrays of data objects:

```
{ id: 4068,
  messages: 
   [ { id: 2,
       title: 'Customer',
       _pivot_user_id: '1',
       _pivot_user_role_id: '2' } ],
  interests: 
   [ { id: 86,
       name: 'interest1',
       _pivot_user_id: '4068',
       _pivot_org_id: '86' } ] }
```

If I try to JSON'ify it, I get error:

> user.toJSON is not a function

```
var user = {
  id: user.id,
  prop1: user.related('messages'),
  prop2: user.related('interests'),
};
return user.toJSON();
```

How do I return the array of objects per related objects for User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
return user.toJSON();
```

try doing:

```
return JSON.stringify(user);
```

if you really want JSON, or this:

```
var user = {
  id: user.id,
  prop1: user.related('messages').toJSON(),
  prop2: user.related('interests').toJSON(),
};
```

if you want a JS object that would look like before serializing to JSON.

Comment: rsp thanks for this- even from reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734894/difference-between-tojson-and-json-stringify I don't understand why json stringify works, but toJSON doesn't

Comment: @Growler `JSON.stringify()` if a method on the global `JSON` object that is also available so the method is also always available. the `.toJSON()` method is a method of a given object, like the object returned by `user.related('messages')` in your example but this is the object than must have that method and not every object does. Try: `var x = 123; JSON.stringify(x);` and then `var x = 123; x.toJSON();` Here `x` doesn't have that method so you cannot call it.