# Using toJSON() to access properties of objects

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```
listData.forEach(function (row, index) {
    console.log(row);       --> output JSON format { _id: 5b0bbae16fcc45381a679186, item1: 'item1', item2: 'item2' }
    console.log(row.item1); --> output undefined

    // If using toJSON() then OK
    var json = row.toJSON();
    console.log(json.item1); --> output item1
});
```

listData: have get Data from MongoDB with mongoose

But I do not understand why so

> [If using toJSON() then OK] although row is JSON format

Comment: Where does listData come from? I'm asking this because json is not by default an object but a string. In javascript it has to be parsed as a json object.

Comment: Looks like the output is not in JSON format, it is a JS object.

Comment: thanks for care. @Jeroen 
listData: get from MongoDB with mongoose  `DataMaster.find({ table: 1 }).sort('-created').exec()`

Comment: thanks for care. @Teemu .  If it is a JS object, values can get by `row.item1` ?

Comment: That's (object) what you've written to your example. Don't guess, check the type.

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734894/difference-between-tojson-and-json-stringify

Comment: @Jeroen Not related, the linked article is related to backbone, this is related to node.js.

Comment: have checked the type, it is a object

Comment: I'm using mongoose, retrieving values from the DB. This is my code `DataMaster.find({ table: 1 }).sort('-created').exec()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose queries will return *MongooseDocuments* and not the plain JavaScript objects.

Try using the [lean()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) method, something like this:

`DataMaster.find({ table: 1 }).sort('-created').lean().exec()`

Comment: I have used lean() method. and It is OK (no need to use toJSON()) access properties of objects. Because Mongoose queries will return MongooseDocuments. Thanks for help

Comment: @TinhNQ glad that helped! happy coding